# Extract solution from question and post it as answer

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I keep running into questions where the OP found the solution to their problem either with the help of some comments, or based on an answer, and they decided to edit the solution into the problem.

I'm sure many have seen questions ending with something like this:

- `SOLVED: ...`
- `Edit: solved. I had to...`
- `Thanks to user @abc, found the solution: ...`

What I usually do is I leave a comment asking the OP to move that part from the question into a dedicated answer. This has about a 50% success rate, which is not bad, but it still leaves lots of questions in an "invalid" state, and with a pending comment that might never be addressed.

So, for questions where the OP doesn't take action, is it ok in this case, to edit the question myself, and move the solution part to a dedicated answer, marked as `Community wiki`, and mentioning at the beginning that it was extracted from the question? I did this 1 or 2 times in the past, however I'm not sure if this is good or bad behaviour.

If it's not ok, what would be a suitable solution instead? This kind of questions break the SO format, so they need to be fixed somehow.

If this is ok, what would be a good waiting period before making the edit myself? I am thinking to something like a month.